# how to iterate through two lists and not repeat values?

Tags: python, list, loops

I'm learning python and I've come across this problem that seems very simple, but I can't find a way

I have two lists:

```
animals = ['cat', 'dog']
animals_name = ['rex', 'laika']
```

I tried:

```
for animal in animals:
    for name in enumerate(animals_name):
        print(animal, name)
```

and got:

```
cat (0, 'rex')
cat (1, 'laika')
dog (0, 'rex')
dog (1, 'laika')
```

I was hoping to get:

```
cat rex
dog laika
```

Comment: `zip(animals, animals_name)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `zip()` function:

```
list(zip(animals, animals_name))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
animals = ['cat', 'dog']
animals_name = ['rex', 'laika']


for index, value in enumerate(animals):
    print(animals[index], animals_name[index], sep=' ')
```

output

```
cat rex
dog laika
```